# Convert string to numbers in Lua

Tags: lua

In Lua, I have a string like this: `231 523 402 1223 9043 -1 4` which contains several numbers separated by space. Now I would like to convert it into a vector of int numbers, how to achieve it with some built-in functions?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [string.gsub](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub) with a function as the replacement value.

> If repl is a function, then this function is called every time a match occurs, with all captured substrings passed as arguments, in order.

An example of usage would look like this:

```
local function tovector(s)
    local t = {}
    s:gsub('%-?%d+', function(n) t[#t+1] = tonumber(n) end)
    return t
end
```

Using it is straight forward:

```
local t = tovector '231 523 402 1223 9043 -1 4'
```

The result is a vector (or sequence in Lua terminology):

```
for i,v in ipairs(t) do print(i,v) end

1       231
2       523
3       402
4       1223
5       9043
6       -1
7       4
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `tonumber` to convert strings to numbers.
Use string patterns to get the numbers from the string
http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.gmatch

```
local example = "123 321 -2"
for strNumber in string.gmatch(example, "%-?%d+") do
  tonumber(strNumber)
end
```

`%-` will match a minus sign, while `%-?` will match minus sign optionally, in other words, there *may be* a minus.

`%d+` will match any string segment that consists of one or more consequent  digits.

Once you have your numbers you can insert them into a Lua table.
http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.insert

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the list into this code

```
return {231,523,402,1223,9043,-1,4}
```

and let Lua do the hard work:

```
s="231 523 402 1223 9043 -1 4"
t=loadstring("return {"..s:gsub("%s+",",").."}")()
for k,v in ipairs(t) do print(k,v) end
```

Comment: Uh, no, just no. eval is bad anywhere you can do without it.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov - You can check untrusted string before evil()ization by matching whole string to the pattern `^[-%d%s]+$`.  Can you create a malicious string to match that pattern? )))